# Recaptcha dissappears after form submission

Tags: captcha

I am using webform with ajax and for spam protection I am using recaptcha module. Everything works fine when form is submitted once with all fields filled and recaptcha is also appearing on it. But when some validation error comes or recaptcha is left i.e. not filled the form appears again with error but their is no recaptcha field. Kindle tell me how to solve this as I am new to Drupal world. I am sure this isthis issue has been discussed before but I am unable to understand their solutions. Kindly give me a solution to solve this. I am using drupal 8.5.4.

Answer (score 0):

check the "Persistence" option in the CAPTCHA settings? You must choose "Always add a challenge".